# How to disable to right navigation bar button in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I have 2 navigation bar buttons added and display it at right. I used this code below and works fine.

```
UIBarButtonItem right = [getUI navBarButtonHistory:self navLink:@selector(btn_sendPreview:) imageNamed:@"ic_print.png"];


UIBarButtonItem  rightPending = [getUI navBarButtonHistory:self navLink:@selector(btn_pending:) imageNamed:@"ic_pending.png"];
```

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[right,rightPending];

but my problem is how to disable that two buttons when i click another button?

Comment: write self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil; in which you don't want to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your IBAction method. You disable those two buttons by traversing through right button items.

```
for(UIBarButtonItem *button in self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems) {
    button.enabled = NO;
}
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: yes, that's what i want. Thank you so much LongNV, keep up the good work.